# Golang: forward ssh over websocket

Tags: ssh, go, websocket

I've been able to forward telnet over a websocket using golang, using something like

```
func forwardtcp(wsconn *websocket.Conn, conn *telnet.Conn) {
    connbuf := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    tcpbuffer := make([]byte, 128)

    for {
        n, err := connbuf.Read(tcpbuffer)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("TCP Read failed")
            break
        }
        if err == nil {
            wsconn.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, tcpbuffer[:n])
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm unable to do similar with an SSH or shell session. I'm not understanding a fundamental concept with the using the

```
targetStdout, _ := session.StdoutPipe()
targetStdin, _ := session.StdinPipe()
```

pieces.

I am able to use io.Copy, but not sure how to format these into a datagram that can be sent with the websocket connection.

Is it possible to treat the targetStdin and targetStdout pipes in a manner that they can be read and written to with bytes, such as those received from the websocket connection?
Or is there a better approach to get io from the SSH connection?

Comment: Yes - for a browser-based client.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SSH for a remote shell session you should not use the websocket package but the [golang.org/x/crypto/ssh](http://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) package. There is an  excellent example at [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Dial) which I repeat here:

```
// An SSH client is represented with a ClientConn. Currently only
// the "password" authentication method is supported.
//
// To authenticate with the remote server you must pass at least one
// implementation of AuthMethod via the Auth field in ClientConfig.
config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "username",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password("yourpassword"),
    },
}
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "yourserver.com:22", config)
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
}

// Each ClientConn can support multiple interactive sessions,
// represented by a Session.
session, err := client.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to create session: " + err.Error())
}
defer session.Close()

// Once a Session is created, you can execute a single command on
// the remote side using the Run method.
var b bytes.Buffer
session.Stdout = &b
if err := session.Run("/usr/bin/whoami"); err != nil {
    panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(b.String())
```

You probably want to use the fields of the `ssh.Session` struct instead of using `StdoutPipe()`.

```
type Session struct {
    Stdin io.Reader
    Stdout io.Writer
    Stderr io.Writer
}
```

The line in the example `session.Stdout = &b` means that the stdout from the remote process will be written to `b`. Likewise, you can assign any `io.Reader` to `session.Stdin` which will be read as stdin by the remote process. The detailed behavior of `ssh.Session` can be found at [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session)

Comment: Thanks - I do need to forward it to a remote browser-based client though - which is where I'm getting stuck.
Executing a single command is a good start, but ideally I'd like to forward for an interactive session.

Comment: For posterity: GoTTY project allows you to run a command on remote server and allows you to see the terminal session from a web browser. You may use command-line utility gotty-client instead of a browser, since that uses websockets to talk to GoTTY server.

Answer (score 1):

A `websocket.Conn` is a `ReadWriter`, so it can be both the source and destination for `io.Copy`. Both `Cmd.StdoutPipe` and `Session.StdoutPipe` are `io.Reader` and the `Stdin` versions are `io.Writer`. So everything should glue together just fine. You just have to copy in both directions.

```
go io.Copy(targetStdin, wsconn)
io.Copy(wsconn, targetStdout)
```

Comment: I tried using the Gorilla websocket implementation and get an error:
`cannot use wsConn (type *websocket.Conn) as type io.Reader in argument to io.Copy:
 *websocket.Conn does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)
and
 cannot use wsConn (type *websocket.Conn) as type io.Writer in argument to io.Copy:
 *websocket.Conn does not implement io.Writer (missing Write method)
  have websocket.write(int, time.Time, ...[]byte) error
  want Write([]byte) (int, error)`

I'm trying using NextReader() and NextWriter() but no luck so far.

Comment: You should look at golang.org/x/net/websocket instead. But you can also wrap the gorilla version in your own type and then add Read and Write methods to it.

Comment: @SimonKnight Any luck using the Gorilla websocket library?